# groovy filter fields in json response

Tags: javascript, json, groovy

I'm trying to filter out some fields in my JSON response.
Sample response below:

```
{
  "Status": "Fail",
  "Code": "500",
  "Rules": [{
      "Status": "Fail",
      "Message": "Code error",
      "id": "123456"
    },
    {
      "Status": "Fail",
      "Message": "Configuration error",
      "id": "12345"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to omit code and id fields and print rest of the fields in JSON.
the final response should look like this:-

```
{
  "Status": "Fail",
  "Rules": [{
      "Status": "Fail",
      "Message": "Code error"
    },
    {
      "Status": "Fail",
      "Message": "Configuration error"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea on how we can achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Groovy already provide classes and mechanisms to do this, first you need to import class **groovy.json.JsonGenerator**

Then you can define the fields that you want to ignore from serilization:

```
def generator = new JsonGenerator.Options()
    .excludeFieldsByName('id', 'Code')
    .build()
```

And finally just need to parse the output:

```
String output = generator.toJson(input)
```

The output will look something like this:

```json
{
    "Status": "Fail",
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Status": "Fail",
            "Message": "Code error"
        },
        {
            "Status": "Fail",
            "Message": "Configuration error"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is a full sample of how I did this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonGenerator

String json = '''{
  "Status": "Fail",
  "Code": "500",
  "Rules": [{
      "Status": "Fail",
      "Message": "Code error",
      "id": "123456"
    },
    {
      "Status": "Fail",
      "Message": "Configuration error",
      "id": "12345"
    }
  ]
}'''

Map input = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

def generator = new JsonGenerator.Options()
    .excludeFieldsByName('id', 'Code')
    .build()

String output = generator.toJson(input)

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(output)
```

To see more configurations for this **JsonGenerator** class you can go to official documentation here: https://groovy-lang.org/json.html#_customizing_output

Comment: Getting the below error when Generator is used. startup failed:
_GroovyUserScript_: 3: unable to resolve class groovy.json.JsonGenerator
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import groovy.json.JsonGenerator
   ^

_GroovyUserScript_: 23: unable to resolve class JsonGenerator.Options 
 @ line 23, column 17.
   def generator = new JsonGenerator.Options()

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using groovy 3.0.6 for that example, maybe if you try with that version you will no longer see that error.

Comment: Thanks for this, I keep forgetting the JasonGenerator class and falling back on old habits. I think this should be the accepted answer as long as we are on a late version of groovy and as long as the op only needs to filter the output string, not the groovy map/list structure.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var getData = {
  "Status": "Fail",
  "Code": "500",
  "Rules": [{
      "Status": "Fail",
      "Message": "Code error",
      "id": "123456"
    },
    {
      "Status": "Fail",
      "Message": "Configuration error",
      "id": "12345"
    }
  ]
};
delete getData.Code;
for (var i = 0; i < getData.Rules.length; i++) {
  delete getData.Rules[i].id;
}
console.log(getData);
```

Note:- You can simply use `delete elementValue` to achieve that

Comment: Thank you, this will be more complex when we have in depth recursive data which is in my case.  Is there a way we cherry pick certain fields and construct a new json, instead of deleting the fields.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
    "Status": "Fail",
    "Code": "500",
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Status": "Fail",
            "Message": "Code error",
            "id": "123456"
        },
        {
            "Status": "Fail",
            "Message": "Configuration error",
            "id": "12345"
        }
    ]
}

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr !== "Code") {
    acc = {
      ...acc,
      [curr]: obj[curr]
    }
  }
  if (curr === "Rules") {
    acc = {
      ...acc,
      [curr]: obj[curr].map(rule => {
        delete rule.id
        return rule
      })
    }
  }
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution which recursively walks through your json and removes specific fields on any depth:

```
import groovy.json.*

def str = '''
{
  "Status": "Fail",
  "Code": "500",
  "Rules": [{
      "Status": "Fail",
      "Message": "Code error",
      "id": "123456"
    },
    {
      "Status": "Fail",
      "Message": "Configuration error",
      "id": "12345"
    }
  ]
}'''

def json  = new JsonSlurper().parseText(str)
def clean = recursivelyRemove(json, ['id', 'Code'])

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(clean))

def recursivelyRemove(obj, fieldNames) {
  switch(obj) {
    case Map:
      obj.findAll { k, v -> 
        !(k in fieldNames)
      }.collectEntries { k, v -> 
        [k, recursivelyRemove(v, fieldNames)]
      }
      break
    case List:
      obj.collect { recursivelyRemove(it, fieldNames) }
      break
    default: 
      obj
  }
}
```

which prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy                                                                                              1 ↵
{
    "Status": "Fail",
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Status": "Fail",
            "Message": "Code error"
        },
        {
            "Status": "Fail",
            "Message": "Configuration error"
        }
    ]
}
```

when run.

This has the upside that it is not hard-coded to your json structure, i.e. if the structure changes for some reason, this code might still work.

A potential downside is that if your json structure is very deep (say hundreds or thousands of levels of nesting), you might get a StackOverflowException as we are making recursive calls. This might or might not be likely depending on your scenario.

Comment: Correct, my data is very recursive. moreover this is working when we declare static data in variable. i tried it on data which is a response from API call which didn't work.

Comment: I would guess there is some structural difference in the response data. Any chance you could add that sample data to the question?

Comment: jsonSlurper.parseText is printing like {Status=Fail, Code=500, Rules=[{}, {id=12345}]} when i test in IDE, but the same when i print in Jenkins stage, it printing [Status:Fail, Code:500, Rules:[[], {id:12345]]]. Any idea why the curly braces and = are printing in a different way?

Comment: Would guess that the response json differs between the two invocations, but it's hard to say without more information. If parse fails that would probably be an indication that the in data is not valid json. This is more common than you would think. Missing quotes, missing commas, malformed identifier names etc.